# TeXnicCenter keyboard shortcut to move outside math environment?

Tags: texniccenter, keyboard

Suppose in TeXnicCenter I use keyboard shortcut to get some environment like this (or any other):

```
\begin{equation} 
\end{equation}
```

After finishing with equation cursor stays inside and one need to type a few additional keyboard buttons (usually arrows) to move outside and continue writing. Things are worse if cursor is somewhere in the middle (because of, for example, changing some text).

Is there some keyboard shortcut which moves cursor automatically outside environment, ready for continuation?

Comment: What version of TeXnicCenter are you using?

Comment: With all respect, the required keystroke to get out of that is a down arrow.

Comment: @Werner - 1.0 stable rc1.

Comment: @percusse - I'am afraid it is not what I asked for.

Comment: The only way I can see this being possible is if it is included as a [feature request for TXC 2.0](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=36323&atid=479426&status=1) - currently in Alpha - since it allows code folding (something not possible in TXC 1.0 Stable RC1). Perhaps, upon code folding via some key combination, your cursor could be set outside the environment.

Comment: @Werner - Thanks for your effort. However I find it very strange that noone before asked for such natural feature, which absence is really annoying.

Comment: Remember that you want an editor-specific requirement (and this editor only runs on Windows). Moreover, as mentioned by @percusse, most users would just use the cursor (our mouse) to move where they want in their source document. TeXnicCenter also lacks "keystroke macro recording" - [something that is part of vim](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/) and helps with automation. There may be other editors that you should try that supports your requested functionality. See this list of [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764).

Comment: @Werner - Thanks again for suggestions, right now Vim is not an option for me. For some other reasons I just moved to TeXstudio and same question arise. Am I allowed now to change my question to not be editor specific?

Comment: "closed as too localised"?

Comment: "closed as too localised"? 1. Relevant to small geographic area - nope; 2. Relevant to specific moment in time - nope; 3. Extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet - nope; Texniccenter is wide aplicable and worldwide popular tool. According to rules (http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) this is totally legitimate question ("Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc."). Btw in my comment above I suggest that question should not be related only to Texniccenter, because same problem arose in almost all IDE's.